# An exception of type 'System.InsufficientExecutionStackException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code in nopcommerce 3.80

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce-3.80

The topic error shows when I add the **method** in **common controller** and call that method from **Header view** file which is located under the **Theme => View => Shared** in **nopcommerce 3.80**.

Here is my method which I call from common controller

```
public ActionResult MobileBrowser()
{
    var browser = Request.Browser;
    System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase myBrowserCaps = browser;
    if (((System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase)myBrowserCaps).IsMobileDevice)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "mob";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "web";
    }
    return View();
}
```

Here is the View file of **MobileBrowser** method

```
@if (ViewBag.Message == "mob")
{
    Mobile
}

@if (ViewBag.Message == "web")
{
    Web
}
```

Here is the **Header.cshtml** from where I calling **MobileBrowser** method from **common** controller

```
@Html.Action("MobileBrowser", "Common")
```

Comment: `InsufficientExecutionStackException` often indicates that the recursive action was executed, especially if you put `@Html.Action` or `@Html.RenderAction` in a certain view which pointing to same action name which returns the view page. I guess that `@Html.Action` helper is the culprit, try using different action name.

Comment: can you suggest me different action name

Comment: The execution flow seem starts from calling controller action => return view => view has `@Html.Action` to same action => return same view again and the cycle will repeat indefinitely until `StackOverflowException` reached. Since you're using header view, could you try return partial view instead?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, I code the **partialview** in the replace of **view**. Special Thankx to  **Tetsuya Yamamoto** for the suggestion.